# Replacing all instances of multiple single characters with new characters in a string

Tags: javascript

Does JavaScript have a function like PHP's string translate? I need to replace all instances of special characters in a string with a specific replacement. For example: 0 => A, 1 => B, 2 => Y, 3 => Z.

In PHP I could do:

```
strtr('string01230123', '0123', 'ABYZ');
```

But in JavaScript, I am currently accomplishing this with stringing a bunch of replace functions.

```
'string01230123'.replace(/0/g, "A").replace(/1/g, "B").replace(/2/g, "Y").replace(/3/g, "Z");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an object mapping characters to their replacements, then construct a regex from the object's keys:

```js
const replacements = {
  0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'Y',
  3: 'Z',
};
const pattern = new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join('|'), 'g');
console.log('string01230123'.replace(pattern, char => replacements[char]));
```

Another way, to construct the object a bit more concisely, if you have *lots* of characters to replace:

```js
const replacements = Object.fromEntries(
`
0 A
1 B
2 Y
3 Z
`
  .split('\n')
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(line => [line[0], line[2]])
);

const pattern = new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join('|'), 'g');
console.log('string01230123'.replace(pattern, char => replacements[char]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the same method. Going to have to make a look up object that combines the two and then either a regular expression or some sort of loop to do the replacements.

```js
const strtr = (str, matches, replacements) => {
  const matchesArr = matches.split('');
  const lookup = matchesArr.reduce((o, c, i) => ({ ...o,
    [c]: replacements[i]
  }), {});
  return str.replace(new RegExp(matchesArr.join('|'), 'g'), x => lookup[x]);
}

console.log(strtr('string01230123', '0123', 'ABYZ'));


const strtr2 = (str, matches, replacements) => {
  const matchesArr = matches.split('');
  const lookup = matchesArr.reduce((o, c, i) => ({ ...o,
    [c]: replacements[i]
  }), {});
  return str.split('').map(x => lookup[x] || x).join('')
}

console.log(strtr2('string01230123', '0123', 'ABYZ'));
```